# Why does Google Sheet SUM not work on my Query result set

Tags: google-sheets

With small examples I can get it to work, but with the result from a larger query I can't. Although I can see the query gives a numerical list back, the functions COUNT OR SUM don't give the expected results.

My table has the following formula in A1:

```
=QUERY('All Items'!$A$2:$AM$796, "SELECT AD WHERE AB IS NOT NULL AND AC IS NOT NULL AND AD IS NOT NULL AND AD <> ' ' LIMIT 10", 0)
```

The result that comes back is:

```
10
14
25
8
7
1
28
2
7
1
```

When I change the formula to give the COUNT of values:

```
=COUNT(QUERY('All Items'!$A$2:$AM$796, "SELECT AD WHERE AB IS NOT NULL AND AC IS NOT NULL AND AD IS NOT NULL AND AD <> ' ' LIMIT 10", 0))
```

The result is

```
0
```

When I try SUM the result is the same.

With a simple test as follows, I can see the functions work:

[image]

What could be causing SUM/COUNT not to work on my first query results?

Comment: How about `counta`?

Comment: counta returns 10. Does this suggest that some of the types in my results are not numeric?

Comment: Not numeric. need: `sum(arrayformula(query(...)*1))`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! If you post that as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not numeric. need:

`sum(arrayformula(query(...)*1))`

test:

use `counta` VS `count` to know your data is not numeric.